# Is $Var(X) = \sum_{y\in D(Y)} Var(X|Y=y) P(Y=y)$, where $D(Y)$ is the domain of $Y$?

Tags: probability

I know that this works for expected values,
$$E(X) = \sum_{y \in D(Y)} E(X | Y=y)  P(Y=y)$$
Does it work for variances, or perhaps $E(X^2)$ or higher moments? If not, is there anything similarly useful? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this doesn't work. You need to look up the Conditional Variance Formula or [Law of Total Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance). There's an extra term coming from the variance of the conditional expectation.

Comment: The formula that I was thinking of is right before the "contents" box on that article. I knew about the law of total variance but not this case. Thank you!

Comment: @SamuelReid, but this does work for higher moments and in general you can write it for any function $f(X)$ (just introducing a new variable $X'=f(X)$). NB: Don't forget to accept Ted Shifrin's answer if you feel it is sufficient or add a comment if something it still unclear.

Comment: Hold up. So it IS true that $E(X^2) = \sum E(X^2 | Y=y) P(Y=y)$?

Comment: Expectation of *any* random variable obeys the Bayesian rule, yes.